# 2 lines in notification bar breaks layout

Tags: bug, status-declined, notifications

So I got the Tumbleweed badge for having an old topic (not entirely sure why thats a badge...) but since the topic name is quite long, it first covers up the user bar and (in Firefox) puts 0 spacing between lines.

Here's how it looks in Firefox 3.6.6 in Windows
[Firefox Notification Bar http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/7613/largebar.png](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/7613/largebar.png)

In Google Chrome Dev and Chromium Standard in Linux the spacing between lines is normal, but it still covers the user bar.

Shouldn't the notification bar push down the page to fit all of itself, not just the first line? This looks like the page spacing was explicitly defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't consider that "broken", per se; just click the close button to dismiss the message.

Comment: Its not a glaring bug, but is something that does need fixing. And the general "just ignore it for now" isn't what I would call a fix. Why is it hard to fix it? Shouldn't it just be a few CSS edits? 6 people apparently really want it fixed.

Comment: Another solution would be to simply truncate the name of the question after 50 or so characters and add ellipsis. There's a link to the question itself anyway.

Comment: Accepting this because the request was declined. *sigh

Comment: Some of us don't close some of these messages and ignore them. I had the same issue until I noticed I had to close it to find the log in link. The proper web usable way is to push the page down so nothing in the original page gets blocked.