# Limit the size of banner messages

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 lines in notification bar breaks layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/2-lines-in-notification-bar-breaks-layout)

The "first time here" banner on some sites has gotten out of hand. See here:

[image: banner covers up important things]

I've been using SE sites for long enough to know that the few pixels poking down from the banner belong to the "log in" link, but a newish user probably wouldn't. And good luck finding the FAQ, about page, SE dropdown, &c. I know, there's a "close this banner" box, but it's not very conspicuous, and we probably don't want to be making users' lives more annoying anyways. Can there be a cap on the length/size of these banner messages?

*PS There's a grammatical error in the banner text, but in the interest of keeping distinct issues separate, I'll post that as a separate question in a moment. **EDIT**: [here it is](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/grammar-error-in-new-user-banner-message).*

*PPS For those keeping score at home, I have now fulfilled [my campaign promise](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=freehand+drop+shadow&room=89) to provide a freehand circle with a freehand drop shadow.*

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/2-lines-in-notification-bar-breaks-layout . For some reason Jeff doesn't feel like fixing it

Comment: @TheLQ, good catch, voting to close, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the behaviour that you describe.  I have tested this in Chrome, FireFox & IE9 (Yep 9!) and they all look like this:
[image]

It must be to do with screen resolution?

I really can't see your point about closing the box - I mean the [X] is pretty big.

I think a better suggestion would be for the box to just fade out after 10-15 seconds.  That way you have displayed a message to user and given them a chance to act on it.  If they don't then the box will disappear and they will have to fend for themselves so to speak.

Comment: It just depends on how big your browser window is. The links are visible if the message doesn't wrap.

Comment: Not a fan of the 10-15 second fadeout; I tend to open 20 tabs worth of SE sites all at once, so I would miss a lot of notifications that way.

Comment: @Popular And on the flip side, if you go to the site and want to login immediately, you probably don't want to wait 10-15 seconds for that bar to fade out