# Grammar error in new user banner message

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

*I originally posted this on the Programmers Meta [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/grammar-error-in-new-user-banner-message), but as @MichaelMrozek pointed out, the same typo is present in all sites' messages.*

The banner message for new/not-logged-in users reads

> Welcome to Q&A site for [site-specific description]...

There should be an article in there:

> Welcome to a Q&A site for...

Or, if we want to be fancier:

> Welcome to the super-mega-ultimate best-on-the-Interblags [site topic] Q&A site!!!!eleven!!

Reference image (ignore the freehand text, I'm reusing an earlier screenshot (hey, I'm being "green")) available [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65401/limit-the-size-of-banner-messages).

[image: banner covers up important things]

Comment: +1 for being "green"

Comment: Just read it out loud... Sounds quite bad as is!!1!1!one!!eleventeen

Comment: I wonder why the english.stackexchange people aren't up in arms about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff has answered [the original post on Meta Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/grammar-error-in-new-user-banner-message/450#450).

Short version: it's fixed.

Slightly less short version: banners now read "Welcome to Q&A for [topic/audience]." This has been implemented systemwide according to a few spot checks.