# Possible Poor grammar on the "Welcome to Stack Overflow" banner

Tags: bug, status-declined, new-users, notification-bar

This was [originally reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65469/grammar-error-in-new-user-banner-message) back in September 2010 but despite being tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) is still a problem:

[image]

It states:

> Welcome to Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers

Surely it should read:

> Welcome to **a** Q&A **site** for ....

or even:

> Welcome to **the** Q&A **site** for ....

(the bold indicates the missing text).

Currently it reads as though it's welcoming the questions and answers **themselves** to the site (thanks [Chris](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162705/chris)). Though you could argue that **is** what the site is about!

The same error is on all the other sites in the network too.

Comment: It's fine when you unpack the abbreviation

Comment: What? "Welcome to Question and Answer for professional ...". Still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Unpack and *pluralize*.

Comment: "Q&A" is pretty much colloquially used in this sense these days. For example, at a presentation someone will say "We'll have Q&A at the end" and the meaning is pretty clear.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Yes, but that doesn't equate to this usage. At least I don't see that it does.

Comment: "Questions and Answers" are in the collective and the thing what is done been talked of.

Comment: It's *technically* fine when you unpack the abbreviation, but reading it is still a bit like throwing up in your mouth. At least welcome people to `<sitename>`, which is described as "Q&A for `<whatever>`".

Comment: Technically fine is the best kind of nanny to oversee your children

Comment: I vote for option #3: "Welcome to the Q&A site for ...." or maybe "Welcome to the best Q&A site for ..." :)

Comment: We ain't gonna have none of your book lernin' round here.

Comment: "Welcome to a/the Q&A site" is like "Welcome to a football stadium" or "Welcome to the Jones ranch." "Welcome to Q&A" is like "Welcome to football" or "Welcome to Jones." Colloquially, I can kinda see how "welcome to Q&A" works, but that doesn't make it _correct_, strictly speaking.

Comment: I was going to take this to English SE, but [John already did](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46688/welcome-to-qa-for-or-welcome-to-a-qa-site-for).

Comment: What is Poor's next move?

Comment: Why the close votes? Is that the correct approach to proposals you disagree with?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm IMHO, it is the correct approach to proposals that incite debate like this.  The team could come settle this with a wave of their hand, and they're really *the only* people who *can* settle this.  After I realized that no one seems to be able to understand anyone else's viewpoint, the conversation became not constructive.  Hence I VTC-ed as not contructive.

Answer (score 25):

The sentence is grammatically correct. You can be welcomed to an activity.

e.g. you can say

> Welcome to training for lorry drivers.

You don't have to say

> Welcome to the place where you are going to do lorry driver training.

Addendum:

In case it's not clear; *Q&A* or *Q and A* is defined as an activity:

> **noun** *Informal.* an exchange of questions and answers.

From http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/q+and+a

It shouldn't be used in a formal context, but I don't think the welcome banner of the website is a formal context.

Comment: It may be grammatically correct, but it still sounds weird.

Answer (score 2):

It originally read (abbreviations expanded):

> Welcome to question(s) and answer(s) site for [site-specific description]

That is grammatically incorrect.  It was changed to:

> Welcome to questions and answers for [site-specific description]

I don't see the problem here.  This *is* correct.

Stack Overflow houses questions and answers for professional and enthusiast programmers, so when people get here we say "Welcome to questions and answers for professional and enthusiast programmers".

Instead of saying:

> "Welcome to questions for professional and enthusiast programmers and also welcome to answers for professional and enthusiast programmers"

we just say

> Welcome to questions and answers for professional and enthusiast programmers"

Another way to put it is that you are welcome to the questions and answers housed on the site, hence we welcome you *to questions and answers*.

For what it's worth, [I asked in the EL&U chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2293911#2293911) and [on the main site](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/46688/6039).  The one person who responded [in chat said](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2294875#2294875) "what is written is fine as it is".  The jury is still out on the question on the main site, but at the time of this writing, the votes seem to be leaning towards leaving it as is.

Comment: Nope - still doesn't really make sense.

Comment: "Welcome to questions and answers for professional and enthusiast programmers"  I'm sorry, what part of that doesn't make sense?

Comment: How can you welcome someone to "questions and answers"? They're not a "thing" - not even a virtual thing like a website.

Comment: We're welcoming them to questions (which are things) and to answers (also things).

Comment: The current banner sounds like it's greeting the questions and answers *themselves*, rather than the visitors who contribute them.

Comment: @Chris - yes that's it! That's what was bothering me.

Comment: Obviously should be re-written as, "Teh progse greetz u!!"

Comment: I can't see how "Welcome to questions and answers" is right; it sounds ridiculous. "Welcome to a site containing questions and answers" is right, if a bit long-winded

Comment: Actually, it **originally** simply read "First time here?" Not even a welcome.

Comment: @PopularDemand Q&A are tangible things (i.e. nouns). In your example, football is verb, not a noun.

Comment: @PopularDemand Again, you're picking describing words that can't stand on their own.  Q&A certainly can.

Comment: Yes, questions and answers are tangible things, but you cannot visit Q&As, though you _can_ visit a __website__ for Q&As.

Comment: @Nightfirecat The people are still welcome to the questions and the answers, are they not?

Comment: @John, I moved my comments to the question about four minutes after I posted them, sorry for making you look crazy. That said, being a tangible thing is not the right guideline. See "Welcome to carrot!" and "Welcome to your dream!"

Comment: @PopularDemand Don't worry about it.  I'm using to looking crazy.  :P  That said, "Welcome to carrot**s**" (plural, like I said earlier) and "Welcome to your dream" (this one doesn't look like it has to be plural) don't make much sense, but they are *technically* correct.  See "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously".

Comment: Also, markdown ought to work in titles.  :P

Comment: I see that you included ":P" but FYI that's [declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/fix-markdown-smartypants-in-question-titles).

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to state for the record:

When I saw this question I knew the OP was British and educated in literature. It's one of the stylistic differences between British and American English. Having attended a British fee-paying school I was also taught the same. If you look at old British literature, you will also see it.

The younger generation isn't too hung up on it due to increasing influence of American media. However those that go to certain schools will certainly be taught it.

Another difference you will see on the internet is the use of 'is' instead of 'are' with regard to entities, such as "Who is ?" vs "Who are ?" in a company's FAQ.

Comment: That's an interesting observation.

Comment: Well you're 50% right. I'm British, but I wouldn't say I was "educated in literature" :)

Comment: I wasn't either. I was looking for a polite way to say "older than me" and "paid attention in a non-failing school" but I'm no author! Were I such a person, I am sure I would have made P G Wodehouse proud!