# Strange punctuation in "Congrats, you've gained the privilege" message

Tags: feature-request, notifications, privileges, notification-bar, spelling

On tex.sx, the privilege banner message is strangely punctuated, and I'm assuming it's the same on other Stack Exchange sites:

[image: Congrats, you've gained the privilege – approve tag wiki edits learn more]

This wording remains the same with the new inbox/notification system:

[image: Congrats, you've gained the privilege – access to moderator tools learn more]

I really wouldn't put a dash there (I confirmed it is a dash and not a hyphen, [at least](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/use-dashes-in-page-titles-instead-of-hyphens)), since a dash introduces some kind of a break, I'd either use

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege: approve tag wiki edits. Learn more.

or

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege “approve tag wiki edits”. Learn more.

or

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege *approve tag wiki edits*. Learn more.

Note that the "learn more" could/should also be considered a sentence by itself, or at least be put in parentheses with one of the above options:

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege *approve tag wiki edits* (learn more).

This last example would be my favorite.

Comment: Good luck with this. [Possible Poor grammar on the "Welcome to Stack Overflow" banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110598/possible-poor-grammar-on-the-welcome-to-stack-overflow-banner)

Comment: It takes a TEX user to notice this :).

Comment: and yet no one is complaining about "congrats" ;)

Comment: @davidsleeps: Just for the record, I don't mind the _Congrats_, which is just in line with the relatively informal American English used on the site.

Comment: I propose we change it to: `Gratz!!!!1!! Plyr 1 LVL UP!! -- approve tag wiki edits.`

Comment: I wonder if this will get the same reaction from Jeff as the [pluralization 'bug' reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/168428) =)

Comment: personally I feel this should simply go in the inbox, don't see a point in having this notifications as huge banners on the site

Comment: @waffles - maybe.  But I think the 10K and 20K banners should stay as a nice, bright congrats to the user :)

Comment: @waffles: It seems to me that you're only displayed each privilege banner message the first time you gain a certain privilege on a stack exchange site. If you gain the same privilege on another site, you don't get the message. Something that visible seems sensible to me, in particular if you want to engage users in moderating activities.

Comment: For what it's worth, I [brought this up on English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75889/is-the-se-new-privilege-notification-message-a-sentence) a few months ago.

Answer (score 11):

[Muphry's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law) is in effect.  But here goes.

---

I agree with OP.  Strunk and White list many uses for a dash; this isn't one of them.

Can we change the text to just `Congrats, you've gained the privilege "approve tag wiki edits".`

Or if we make the first part of the text a complete sentence, then a colon would work:

`Congrats, you've gained the following privilege: "approve tag wiki edits".`

Comment: Hey, you spelled "Murphy's Law" wrogn.

Comment: @Rob - good one :-)

Comment: @RobHruska You spelled wrong wrong! :P

Comment: @Alenanno thatsthejoke.jpg

Comment: @blahdiblah Yeah I kind of figured. It was too cool to be a coincidence.