# Is there a "top banner" also for new users or low-rep users?

Tags: support, new-users, top-bar, unregistered-users

When I view some site without being logged in (or in incognito mode), I see a banner near the top of the site with some basic information about the site. For example, on Meta Stack Exchange I get this information:

> Meta Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites. It only takes a minute to sign up.

**Question.** Is this information displayed only for users without an account and once they sign up, they no longer see it? Is there something similar (banner at the top, some other element on the front page) which shows basic information to users who are relatively new (haven't asked any questions, have still a relatively low reputation)?

My best guess is that this is only shown to unregistered users. (Since when I look at sites where I am a low-rep user with no posts, I do not see any substantial difference between things that I see there and things that I see on sites where I have higher reputation.) But it would be good to have a bit "more official" confirmation - after all, I might have overlooked something.

I am aware that there is a modal window which is shown to first-time askers - it was [announced here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network). But there is a bit of difference between information which is prominently displayed on the frontpage and something which is only displayed after some action. (In this case, after the user has already decided to post a question.)

Browsing here on meta I found out that there used to be something called a "welcome banner" - but it seems that it was removed a long time ago: [Why was the welcome banner removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129118) I searched a bit whether there are some posts showing a screenshot of the welcome banner - this could (probably) be it: [Possible Poor grammar on the "Welcome to Stack Overflow" banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110598).

---

Here is a screenshot showing this banner (on this site):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "no" but can't be 100% sure, [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217061/can-we-continue-to-show-the-take-a-tour-banner-after-a-user-has-created-an-acc) also suggests it's not showing, hence OP asking to implement it.