# A long question title causes the js message bar to be wrapped to 2 lines

Tags: feature-request, questions, bounties, title

I posted a bounty question with a long title over on SO. The reminder of the bounty end-date was split and wrapped over two lines, causing it to hide topmost navigation links (partially).

Is there a way of determining the length of a question and taking that into account, when using it for the js message bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 lines in notification bar breaks layout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/2-lines-in-notification-bar-breaks-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, this is by design. Larger messages take more space to display. Click the x to dismiss the message.

Comment: Ok. If this is by design, then this question can be closed. Thanks for the quick reply!