# Long notifications at page top don't fit and overlap with rest of the page

Tags: bug, notifications, notification-bar, rendering, page-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 lines in notification bar breaks layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/2-lines-in-notification-bar-breaks-layout)

Whenever a StackExchange universe site wants to show a notification that doesn't fit into a single string the message is wrapped around and starts overlapping with the rest of the page - see partial screenshot below:

[image]

Note that this includes messages to people not logged in.

Screenshot taken on Firefox 4.0.1 (same behavior on Firefox 6.smth), Windows XP, screen resolution 1280x1024, "large" 125% fonts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 lines in notification bar breaks layout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/2-lines-in-notification-bar-breaks-layout) (and [Limit the size of banner messages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65401/limit-the-size-of-banner-messages))