# Menu items are cut off when user is logged off with a small window

Tags: bug, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 lines in notification bar breaks layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/2-lines-in-notification-bar-breaks-layout)

[image: announcement banner drops below header bar]

When the user is logged off on any Stack Exchange site, the standard 'Welcome to Q&A' greeting appears at the top of the screen. The entire webpage tries to shift downward by the size of the banner, but it seems to assume that the banner is exactly one line tall. In cases where the browser window is fairly small, the line wraps over and causes the height of the welcome banner to increase, cutting off the menu items.

It's not really anything serious, since the user can just click the 'x' or maximize their screen, but it's been bothering me.

Comment: Brought up before at [2 lines in notification bar breaks layout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/2-lines-in-notification-bar-breaks-layout) and [Limit the size of banner messages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65401/limit-the-size-of-banner-messages). For the lazy, Jeff's answer is "just click the close button" (i.e. not a bug).

Comment: Darn.  Well, I guess I shouldn't be surprised that something as obvious as this was brought up before.  Could somebody close this question, then?  (or delete, if that's more appropriate.)